# How do we upgrade the boost library version in the rhel 7.2 Current boost library version 1.53 , want to upgrade to version 1.54 and above

Tags: c++, boost, rhel7, nghttp2

I want to generate libnghttp2_asio: High level HTTP/2 C++ library on rhel 7.2.
libnghttp2_asio C++ library requires the following packages:

libboost-dev >= 1.54.0

libboost-thread-dev >= 1.54.0

Current boost library installed on rhel 7.2 is version 1.53,
I have tried to upgrade to version 1.54 or above, using yum update boost and downloaded the boost version 1.66 rpm package and tried to install but not able to do its having lot of other dependencies. when try to resolve other dependencies again its having other dependency and so on. and its getting block.

Does rhel 7.2 supports boost version 1.54 and above if so how do we upgdare.

Comment: What did you try? Have you read the instructions? That said, 1.79 is current, so why use an older version?

Comment: the packages management will handle dependencies automatically , you might need to download the boost sources, then build and install them manually

Comment: "and its getting block" - you need to talk more about the actual problem. Otherwise, @nhatnq is 100% right: the package manager will resolve the dependencies.